# What are the security ramifications of allowing a user insert their own JavaScript into our web application?

Tags: javascript

I have a requirement to allow a user to paste a JavaScript block into our servers hand have it added to this users webpage under head(users domain would be customName.oursite.com).  What are the security ramifications of this type of feature?

Comment: Can you specify what else on the user page is customizable?

Comment: The user can change settings for their site, like what pages display what site design they would like to use and fill in text for content blocks.  Their site users fill in a form that is eventual downloadable from another control site.

Comment: If user is already blocked from modifying the content of the webpage (he cannot add javascript into pages), than all answers below apply. Try to see if it's possible to have the js script reviewed before putting it in production, then security is better.

Comment: It is like giving the combination to the vault with a million dollars in it. Look at how facebook does it with the [fbjs](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/fbjs/).

Answer (score 2):

You're letting them do anything that they can do with Javascript, which includes attacks like XSS attacks and CSRF attacks. They can possibly steal sessions, redirect to malicious sites, steal cookie-information, or even lock up users' browsers . Essentially there are many security ramifications and you would also be increasing your liability. Users may associate the bad behavior with your site and may not realize that it is your customer who has included malicious Javascript.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I'll give examples since everyone else explained. I had first hand experience on this as well, just for fun and practice actually:

- One can create a script that makes the page look like your site's login page and record the logins. People will unknowingly login using that fraud page (with a bit of social engineering) and presto! Usernames and passwords.
- One can manipulate and account without the user knowing it. Let's say I have planted malicious code on my profile page that loads an iframe with `http://example.com/account.php`. If the user visits the page with the script, the iframe will load with the accounts page. Since the user is logged in, his information will be shown. The script can then scrape the iframe (since it's the same domain), and forward it to the hacker's server via GET request (serialized URL).
- One can plant cookies and track you. When an unsuspecting user visits a malicious page, the script can read all the cookies, forward it to the hacker's server. Since cookies are used on pretty much everything (from saving sessions, to storing shopping cart information), you've been exposed.
- One can know what sites you have been on using the "visited links are purple" technique. The script can generate a list of links on the DOM, check which of them are purple, and then forward that "purple list" to the hackers.
- Plant a spamming script, using the user's credentials. Say a malicious code scans the rest of the pages on your site for Facebook like buttons, then clicks them or initiates the GET/POST for the like - without them knowing. In the end, the user won't know they liked a million pages.
- and so much more.. care to suggest a few possible ones?

In short, letting users post arbitrary scripts, especially in a shared space, is... unspeakable evil.

---

If you are running a web hosting service, each user should have his/her own "space" separate from the other users and separate from the main site. That's the reason why in free hosting, a user has an own subdomain, or in a paid hosting, an own domain. The user can do whatever they want to their space *without compromising** the host or the other users under it.

<sub>* There are some exceptions. Since the user has the freedom to do anything to their space, they can turn their space into a fully malicious site. And still, other users should exercise basic site security. Even if they are in another space, there are still *a lot* of ways to gain entry or do something sinister.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Cross site scripting attack is a big one

Answer (score 1):

XSS is the biggest issue. This could allow access to cookies, pages, give elevated privileges or redirect to malicious pages that could result in viruses across the user's machine or even a server(s).

Answer (score 1):

Think of this from two perspectives: First, users can pretty much already do this via bookmarklets and the browser's development tools javascript console. Thus your servers should ALREADY be hardened against malicious clients. Remember while users may access your site with a browser, attackers can attack with arbitrary HTTP or TCP messages, and you must handle that. So from the beginning, you should be designing your server to treat the client as untrusted as best and hostile at worst.

Now specifically, it's pretty rare for sites to allow this sort of thing because as you correctly imagine, it does make things much more tricky. However, many applications need this type of solution. So just keep in mind that data you send out from your server may be accessed by untrusted, broken, leaky (in terms of privacy), or otherwise insecure user-authored javascript. Don't trust that your javascript can do any authorization filtering in the browser. All data leaving the server must already be properly filtered for authorization, and never assume your server will receive valid/authorized requests.

Answer (score -1):

I think the key question is where does the JavaScript execute? If it runs on one page that is only visible to the user, then only that user could be affected by the script. If it's run on a comment board, for example, then other users could be affected by the script. The script might, for example, make an http request to a malicious server, passing along the cookie with the request.

Comment: Not implying your answer is correct with this statement but whether its one user or all users it is still a security issue and shouldn't be done.

Comment: Agreed in general that it shouldn't be done. But I think it's more helpful to understand what the risk is exactly. If the user is only going to hose up their own page, or send their own cookie to their own malicious server, doesn't really matter :-).